# How to Explode row into multiple rows based on value of another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, row

I have a dataframe with values similar to  this (values changed for security) and there are around 1000 lines of data here:

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'Subnet.1.1': ['514.71.90', '871.84.0','33.45.16'], 'Difference' : 
['10','16','4'], 'Location': ['Alaska', 'Hawaii', 'Maine']})

# Result:
                Subnet.1.1  Difference  Location
           0    514.71.90   10          Alaska
           1    871.84.0    16          Hawaii
           2    33.45.16    4           Maine
```

I need to **explode the third octet** of the IP address depending on the value of the 'Difference' column, while keeping the information intact.

the problem is I have 255 (unique values) in the 'Difference' column. and I have written the below code but I really don't want to do a block of text for every occurrence (unique value)and then concat all the new resulting frames together at the end. **I am sure** there is a more positive and efficient way to do this but I can't figure it out.

```
#So what I am thinking is to separate each value into a new dataframe:

subnet_10 = dataframe[dataframe['Difference'] == '10']   # ..and so on
```

**Then run the below code for each subnet:**

```
try:
  df2_10 = subnet_10["Subnet.1.1"].str.split(".", expand=True)

  df3_10 = (df2_10.join(df2_10.
                pop(2). # Extract the third element
                astype(int) # Cast the string to int
                .apply(lambda start: range(start, start+10)) # expand the range
                .explode() # explode into individual rows
                .astype(str) # cast back into str
               )
      )

  df_final_10 = (df3_10[[0, 1, 2]] # Select IPs in the right order
            .agg('.'.join, axis=1) # Rebuild them
            .to_frame(name="Subnet.1.1") # turn into df
            .join(subnet_10.drop("Subnet.1.1", axis=1))) # join with subnet_10 dataframe
except:
  df_final_10 = pd.DataFrame()
```

**So my question is:**

**Is it possible to write a code that will check for each value in the 'Difference' column and and explode the Subnet.1.1 column accordingly without writing a block for each occurrence in the 'Difference' Column?  **

```
Expected Output for each 'Difference' value:

Subnet.1.1   Difference   Location
514.71.90    10           Alaska
514.71.91    10           Alaska
....etc to 
514.71.100   10           Alaska
871.84.0     4            Hawaii
871.84.1     4            Hawaii
etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there has to be a more efficient way to solve this, but this is the best I could come up with for now.
The idea is to make a new temporary column containing a list of all the IPs of the subnet and then use the [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)
function to explode the column. The downside to this is that the `Subnet1.1` column stays the same so you just have to drop it and replace it with the new column.
In order to do that string manipulation I built a simple function that is passed as argument in the [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function.

```py
# create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Subnet.1.1': ['514.71.90', '871.84.0', '33.45.16'],
                   'Difference': ['10', '16', '4'],
                   'Location': ['Alaska', 'Hawaii', 'Maine']})
# define function
def list_of_subnets(row):
    # split IP into 3 its three components
    comps = row['Subnet.1.1'].split(".")
    # get value of Difference column as an integer 
    diff = int(row['Difference'])
    # assemble the IP's components (range goes to diff + 1 as to include the last element)
    return [comps[0] + '.' + comps[1] + '.' + str(int(comps[2])+i) for i in range(diff+1)]

# apply function to a new column
df['temp'] = df.apply(list_of_subnets,axis=1)
# explode 'temp' column
df = df.explode('temp')
# drop and rename columns 
df = df.drop('Subnet.1.1',axis=1).rename(columns={'temp':'Subnet.1.1'})
# rearrange columns to original format
df = df[['Subnet.1.1','Difference','Location']]
```

Output is the same as yours (except the Difference for `IP: 871.84.0` was `16` in the start and `4` in the end, I guess that was a typo).

Comment: Thank you, very much I am going to see what I can do with your function and method. I very much appreciate your input on this!

Answer (score 0):

I think for now the only way is for me to write a block for each occurrence.

I appreciate anyone's time on this and any answer/ response later would be greatly appreciated.